# why socket.disconnect() on client side doesn't fire disconnect event on the server?

Tags: node.js, react-native, socket.io

> ```
> I SOLVED MY PROBLEM WİTH THİS CODE BLOCK
>
>
> var io = require('socket.io')(server, {
>   pingInterval: 10000,
>   pingTimeout: 5000,
> }).listen(server)
> ```

I am making chat app with socket.io. But if i dont make event in 15 or 20 sec , my app disconnect to socket.io. I would like to  just disconnect when app closed

Server side code;

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
let chatroom;
console.log("User Connected");
io.sockets.emit('connected', "12345");
socket.on('chatRoom', function(room) {
socket.join(room);
chatroom = room;
});

socket.on('messageData', function(msg){
  io.sockets.in(chatroom).emit('messageData', msg);
});
 socket.on('disconnect', function(msg){
  console.log("User DisConnected"); 
});

});
```

Client Side Socket Class

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import io from "socket.io-client";

class socketio extends Component{


    static socketConnect = () =>{
       this.socket=io("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000",{jsonp:false});
    }

    static getSocket = () =>{
        return this.socket;
    }
}

export default socketio;
```

Client Side Chat Screen Code;

```
import socketio from '../Classes/socketio';
this.socket = socketio.getSocket();

      this.socket.emit('chatRoom', this.state.chatID);

            this.socket.on("messageData",(data) =>{               

            });
```

Comment: Where's the code that calls `socket.disconnect()`?

Comment: Also, it looks like you are misuing `this`, static methods and fat arrow functions in your `socketio` class.  I don't know if that's causing your particular problem, but it's really poor code that can easily lead to problems and certainly leads to confusion about where the socket is actually being stored.

Comment: My problem is  , If I dont send message and second user doesnt send message in 15 or 20 sec. Server disconnected me automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Your use of `this` inside a far arrow function inside a static method is really, really confusing.  The `this` value will likely be the `this` value in your module which is probably the `module` itself.  In any case, that's not a good place to store your socket and is very, very confusing.

---

I have no idea if this fixes your main issue, but you can fix your use of `this`, static methods and fat arrow functions by changing to this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import io from "socket.io-client";

// module level variable, can only be one connected socket with this design
let socket;

class socketio extends Component{
    static function socketConnect() {
       socket = io("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000",{jsonp:false});
    }

    static function getSocket() {
        if (!socket) {
            throw new Error("Must call socketConnect() before getSocket()");
        }
        return socket;
    }
}

export default socketio;
```

Personally, I have no idea why you're using a design that limits you to one connection rather than creating an instance of your class and then letting that instance store the socket, but given your inclination to design for only one connection, you can just make it a module level variable as above.